# How to host Jupyter notebook on github?

Tags: json, github, jupyter

As I understand it from [this github page](https://github.com/blog/1995-github-jupyter-notebooks-3), I can push a .ipynb to my repo and then run my notebook directly from github.

When I ask my Jupyter to download my notebook as .ipynb, I get a `.ipynb.json`.

What must I do to that file so that github will open that notebook with nbviewer for me?

Comment: Note that the content of `.ipynb` files is valid JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply change `.ipynb.json` to `.ipynb` and then sync your github repo.

if you want open that notebook with nbviewer, click the `prohibitory sign` at the upper right corner of your notebook on the github page and choose `external view available with nbviewer`.